# Django Upload Image Read Content

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have very simple upload form one file input and submit. I am trying to read the content of uploaded file.

Here is the code of the view:

```
def media(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    file_obj = request.FILES['file']

    logger.debug(file_obj.read())
    logger.debug('cnt-type: ' + file_obj.content_type)
    return render(request, 'media.html')
  return render(request, 'media.html', {})
```

file_obj.read() returns nothing if the file is Image. If I upload some text file then it is fine.

How can I read the content of image file ?

Comment: the byte encoding

Comment: What do you mean with text of the image ?